# XSLT: Creating an Output-string considering some Elements aren't existent

Tags: sql, xml, xslt

I have to transform an xml into several insert into statements.

Inside the XML there is a `<xpdl:ExtendedAttributes>`-Element containung up to five `<xpdl:ExtendedAttribute name="attribute1" Value="value1">`-Elements.
The ouput-string mustlook like one of these examples:

```
,'Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5');
,'','','Value3','Value4','Value5');  
etc.
```

The Problem is if I don't set a Value for an Attribute in my program which generates the xml it won't create the `<xpdl:ExtendedAttribute>`-Element.

I tried following code:

```
<xsl:template match="xpdl:ExtendedAttributes">
    <xsl:for-each select="xpdl:ExtendedAttribute">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Name='Value1'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($apos,./@Value,$apos,',')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@Name='Value2'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($apos,./@Value,$apos,',')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@Name='Value3'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($apos,./@Value,$apos,',')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@Name='Value4'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($apos,./@Value,$apos,',')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@Name='Value5'">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($apos,./@Value,$apos,',')"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>'',
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But this doesn't consider the missing attributes. 
Does anybody have ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Several failures I've finally achieved the desired Output.

using a global sequence-variable

`<xsl:variable name="AttributeNames" as="xs:string*" select="('Programm', 'Verantwortlich', 'Beteiligt' ,'Informiert' ,'Prozessschritt')" />`

and following code

```
<xsl:template match="xpdl:Activity/xpdl:ExtendedAttributes">
    <xsl:variable name="input" select="."/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$AttributeNames" >
            <xsl:variable name="attributeName" select="." />
            <xsl:variable name="Value"> 
                <xsl:for-each select="$input/xpdl:ExtendedAttribute">
                    <xsl:variable name="currentNode" select="." />
                        <xsl:choose>
                             <xsl:when test="$attributeName = $currentNode/@Name">
                                  <xsl:value-of select="$currentNode/@Value" />
                             </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(',', $apos,$Value, $apos,$lb)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$input/xpdl:ExtendedAttribute[@Name=current()]" />    
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I've achieved what I'v wanted:

`,''
,'Mitarbeiter'
,''
,''
,'16,0'`
 as an example where only the 2nd and the 5th attribute is existent

Answer (score 0):

If your XML generator doesn't generate an `Extended-Attribute` tag for attributes that has no value, so there is no way to reference them in your XSLT.

There should be a way to tell XSLT processor about what properties (how many `Extended-Attribute` tag) should exists in `Extended-Attributes` collections. This way maybe you can have a XSLT code which looks for those attribute names in the collection and if it couldn't find them, use the default empty apostrophes value. Of course it should be complicated. I suggest to change your XML generator part if you can